# Detect Enter keypress in html input without jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I just want to detect the enter input keypress on my android device. I found out that using jquery, we can do like below:

```
$('#inputText').keypress(function(event) {
var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
if(keycode == '13') {
    alert('You pressed a "enter" key in somewhere');    
}
});
```

But I don't want to use jquery. I want to use the traditional way like using

> document.getElementById('inputText')

But I don't know how to add in the keypress event function. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as in `jQuery`. Use `eventListener` and pass an argument `e` to the function to catch the event and it's `keyCode`.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('inputText');
elem.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('You pressed a "enter" key in somewhere');   
  }
});
```

```html
<input id='inputText'>
```

Comment: @Coolguy I didn't test it by myself, but I guess so.

Comment: @Arun D Thank you for your edit, but I'd prefer to avoid using DOM events, `onkeypress` or `onclick`. (:

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("id").onKeyDown = function(event) {

    if (event.keycode === 13) {
        alert("return pressed");
    }

};
```

Comment: Or keypressed or keyup

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`!

```
const node = document.getElementById('inputText');
node.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener`

document.getElementById('inputText').addEventListener("keypress", function() {});

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
document.getElementById('txtBox').onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == '13') {
    alert("Enter Pressed");

  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txtBox" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<form onsubmit="Search();" action="javascript:void(0);">
<input type="text" id="searchCriteria" placeholder="Search Criteria"/>
<input type="button" onclick="Search();" value="Search" id="searchBtn"/>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to the answer?  Although a code-only answer might fix the problem, it generally won't teach the OP anything, and won't be as useful to future users.